# ways of Calling a constructor in java

Tags: java, constructor

I was told that the way to call a constructor is type object_variable = new type i.e:

```
Fraction f1 = new Fraction( 2, 3 );
```

but I also read on stackoverflow that the way to call a constructor is using the "this." method. Which way is correct or are both ways acceptable? Therefore in this example below would the first line or the one.denominator part be the call to the constructor?:

```
 1  public static Fraction addFraction( Fraction one, Fraction two ) {
 2       int commonDenom = one.denominator * two.denominator;
 3       int newNumerator = one.numerator * two.numerator +
 4                          two.numerator * one.numerator;
 5       return new Fraction( newNumerator, commonDenom );
    }
```

Comment: Where did you read the `this(` method, specifically? It applies to inner types mainly.'

Comment: You can only use `this()` to call one constructor from another constructor.

Comment: this line is calling the constructor `new Fraction( newNumerator, commonDenom );` :S

Comment: `this.` as constructing an inner class with an explicit outer class? (Don't do that.) / Your method there would usually be an instance method called simply `add`. Called as `Fraction sum = a.add(b);` rather than `Fraction sum = Fraction.addFraction(a, b);`.

Answer (score 3):

A class may have two constructors with different argument lists.  You can use `this()` to call one constructor from another constructor of the same class.

e.g.

```
public class Foo {
   private final String value;
   public Foo() {
      this("default");
   }

   public Foo(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
 }
```

When creating a new object, you would never use `new this()`, simply `new Foo()` or `new Foo("myValue")`.

Comment: so in the example I had given would "one." or "two." substitute for this or are they not calling constructors?

Comment: @SophiaAli: Neither.  `this` refers to the instance being acted on, and only has relevance in a constructor or an instance method.  In your example, `addFraction` is a static method, so there is no `this` in scope.

Comment: @SophiaAli: Yes there's a call to the constructor.  You're calling the two-argument constructor of `Fraction`.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore in this example below would the first line or the one.denominator part be the call to the constructor?:

Neither. The *last* line calls the constructor because you are using the `new` operator.